# Uploading fails from an iOS device but it works perfect from the iOS Simulator

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios5, ios-simulator

Have this piece of code that works perfectly when I run this on iOS Simulator. When I run this on the device, I get the file count ZERO on my MVC3 controller.

Here is my Objective C code

```
// create request
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];                                    
[request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];
[request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:YES];
[request setTimeoutInterval:30];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

 NSString *boundary = @"WebKitFormBoundaryAFokZJl5GNWFRG28";

// set Content-Type in HTTP header
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
[request setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"patid\"\r\n\r\n %@", _patID] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"apicall\"\r\n\r\n %@", @"yes"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

// add image data
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);
if (imageData) {
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"image.jpg\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:imageData];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

// setting the body of the post to the reqeust
[request setHTTPBody:body];

// set the content-length
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [body length]];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

NSMutableString *sURL;

sURL = _postURL;

NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:sURL];
[request setURL:url];

NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"%@", returnString);
```

My ASP.NET MVC3 Controller method

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/images/id"), fileName);
            file.SaveAs(path);
        }
        return View();
    }
```

When I run this from the Simulator, I get files (HttpPostedFileBase is not null) on my MVC3 controller. When I run the same code from the Device the file is NULL.

Am I doing something wrong? Can someone please help me...

**EDIT** - Thanks @Martin, you gave me the clue.

I found out the weird problem caused by my corporate proxy server. Following your suggestion I was trying to set up a Fiddler instance on Windows machine and configured it as a proxy for the iPAD. Surprisingly my upload feature worked with out problem, when I tried it back on the corporate proxy - it fails. I will try to figure it soon.. Many thanks for your response @Martin R ...much appreciated.

Comment: What is the output of `NSLog(@"%@", returnString)` when the upload from the device fails?

Comment: The returnString is the View HTML since my "file" object is null and the code directly falls on to the -return View();

Comment: Did you verify that `imageData` is not nil?

Comment: Yes Martin, its perfect. I am guessing there may be some issues with the \r\n sequences and I wonder how it works in Simulator but not on the device...:(

Comment: I would use a network analyzer (e.g. Wireshark) to trace what is actually sent.